# Android Studio buggy since last update to version 1.4

Tags: android, android-studio

I updated to 1.4 in Android Studio and since then Android Studio has appearance/display issues. You can see in the screenshot linked below that text is garbled with parts of it displaying and parts of it not. If you hover over an item in the menu for instance, there is a good chance it will become garbled or text that is already garbled might display. It is like this throughout the program and with the code itself which blinks on and off when selected sometimes.

Am I the only person having this problem? I did a complete wipe and re-install and it is still the same.

[image: SS]

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing font rendering problem on Android Studio since the beginning. I've solved by adding an extra configuration in the startup script, give it a try:

1. locate the file **studio.sh** in your Android Studio directory (I suppose it should be *studio.bat* on Windows)
2. locate the string `-Djb.restart.code=88 -Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio1.4 \`
3. append `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on \` at the end of the previously located line
4. restart Android Studio

*n.b. don't miss the `\` at the end of these lines*

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately I cannot find a file called studio.sh or studio.bat in this windows version. I cannot find any file called studio in fact. Do you remember what exact folder a file like this should be in?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like I was able to resolve the issue by going to:

file>settings>appearance&behavior>appearance>

And then change the theme to something else. 
You can then change it back to whatever you had it on.
(This is on Windows)

Comment: hmm, seems like I cannot even just increase the font size of the editor lest it reverts to its glitchy font rendering ways.